# how to create textbox for searching like Google textbox style

Tags: c#, winforms

Just as simple as this, I need to search an array that is binded to listbox, and user will type the text in a text box, something like Google search text box does.

This is for Windows Application using C# (3.5)

Any idea?

Comment: Is this for a web project? - If so consider googling jQuery autocomplete.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @Kohan

Comment: Giving the information needed to answer the question certainly helps :)

Comment: This is already built into WinForms (see my post below).  Not sure about WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForms TextBox controls have an AutoComplete property.  This behaves the same as the Google TextBox.  Here is an example:

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to use ComboBox, it has [autocomplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx)

This is [simple](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/730.html)

Comment: Well, this is not what I really need, I need when the user enters any value that matches some items in the list, the listbox will show the matched items, just something like Google Search textbox

Comment: If so then ho1 gave the answer, but this is not looks like Google search text box for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is sorted in alphabetical order.

Just handle the `TextChanged` event for the `TextBox` and whenever it changes you use `ListBox.FindString` to find the first item in the `ListBox` that starts with that string and then call `ListBox.TopIndex` with the index of that item to make that be the top visible item in the `ListBox`.